# The C++ code that using templates doesn't compile in c++ 20, but was ok in c++ 17

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20, legacy-code

I have some legacy code that I want to upgrade to c++20. The code compiles in c++17 without any issues but fails if I switch to C++20. I simplified the code as much as possible, please look at the example.  I am using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows

```
class MyFile
{
public:
    void Read(){ }
};

class ArrayWrapper;

class BaseClass
{
public:
    ArrayWrapper* arrayWrapper;
};

template <class T> class ArrayClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    void Add()
    {
        arrayWrapper->file.Read();
    }
};


class ArrayWrapper
{
public:
    ArrayWrapper(): file(new MyFile()){ }
    ~ArrayWrapper() { delete file; }
    MyFile* file;
    ArrayClass<int> Array{};
    void Update()
    {
        Array.Add();
    }
};

int main()
{
    ArrayWrapper wrapper;
    wrapper.Update();
}
```

And this is the error message that I am getting:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'ArrayWrapper'
message : see declaration of 'ArrayWrapper'
message : see reference to class template instantiation 'ArrayClass<T>' being compiled
```

I did look on the stack overflow and in the C++ docs but couldn't figure out what is wrong with this code in C++ 20
Can someone explain how to fix this issue, please?

Comment: This doesn't compile with `/std:c++17`  either. It gives the same expected and self-explanatory error since you have member access into the incomplete type `ArrayWrapper`. What in the error message is unclear?

Comment: Clang 16 gives "error: member access into incomplete type 'ArrayWrapper'
    void Add() { arrayWrapper->file.Read(); }" which might be more helpful - at the point where `arrayWrapper->file.Read()` is encountered, the compiler doesn't know anything about `ArrayWrapper`

Comment: @TedLyngmo compiles with /std:c++17 for me after fixing the error with  `file.Read` which should be `file->Read`  [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dr9TffGz4).

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit  It seems they made it more strict in C++20 mode. Add `/permissive-` when compiling in C++17 mode and it fails there too.

Comment: MSVC lacks two-phase name lookup without `/permissive-`, and setting C++20 or C++latest implies `/permissive-` while setting C++17 does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `ArrayClass::Add` definition after `ArrayWrapper`.

The method and the whole `ArrayClass<int>` is instantiated right after the definition of the class template, at which point `ArrayWrapper` is still not fully defined.

You would get the same error if `ArrayClass` was not a template.

```
class MyFile
{
public:
    void Read(){ }
};

class ArrayWrapper;

class BaseClass
{
public:
    ArrayWrapper* arrayWrapper;
};

template <class T> class ArrayClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    void Add();
};


class ArrayWrapper
{
public:
    ArrayWrapper(): file(new MyFile()){ }
    ~ArrayWrapper() { delete file; }
    MyFile* file;
    ArrayClass<int> Array{};
    void Update()
    {
        Array.Add();
    }
};

template <class T> 
void ArrayClass<T>::Add()
{
    arrayWrapper->file->Read();
}

int main()
{
    ArrayWrapper wrapper;
    wrapper.Update();
}
```

Also, it should be `arrayWrapper->file->Read();` `file` is a pointer.